# DropDown Menu using IEnumerable SelectList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error when trying to select an item from my drop down list and submit this.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'RoleName'.

If anyone can help me figure out how to fix this error I would really appreciate it as I haven't been able to fix it yet and been stuck for quite a long time and google hasn't provided a solution yet!

This is my controller code

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var roles = context.Roles.ToList();

        return View(roles);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "canEdit")]
    public ActionResult ManageUserRoles()
    {
        var list = context.
            Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new   SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (user != null)
        {
            UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, RoleName);
        }
        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

This is my ManageUserRoles View

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "ManageUserRoles";
}


<h2>Manage User Roles</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Role", "Create") | @Html.ActionLink("View User   Roles", "Index")
<hr />

<h2>Role Add to User</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAddToUser", "Roles"))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<p>
    User Name : @Html.TextBox("UserName")
    Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)  ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
<hr />
```

Comment: Where are you adding your roles to the ViewBag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is (I assume) that you are visiting View("ManageUserRoles") from your ActionResult RoleAddToUser and not from ManageUserRoles. So ViewBag does not exists.

```
return View("ManageUserRoles");
```

starts to render view. However on the view you have dropdown which wants ViewBag.Roles ... but ... where do you set data into it? This exception is thrown because ViewBag.Roles just not exist.

If you want run ActionResult ManageUserRoles before returning the view, you have to call redirect.

```
return RedirectToAction("ManageUserRoles");
```

If you want render view without execute code in that method, you have to create ViewBag.Roles in RoleAddToUser. Please, note that ViewBag data are deleted after every request.

Comment: That solved it thanks very much for your help @Ademar

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your model (whether its a domain model or some other viewmodel) has a field of string type called "RoleName", this needs to match the first argument of your DropDownList call so the page knows what variable to post the data back in on form submit.

Comment: I have checked my model and the field is called Name rather than RoleName however after changing all references of RoleName to Name I am still getting the same error